# What is the statistically correct way of performing the following interpolation?

Tags: regression, correlation, clustering, kriging

I have a table with thousands of entries similar to the following:

[image]

It is desired to determine Property 2 at the unknown locations. Property 1 and Property 2 are spatially correlated. By that I mean if you use Latitude and Longitude fields to first cluster your data points based on their spatial proximity, you will get obvious correlations between Property 1 and Property 2 within each cluster; however, if you do not cluster and plot Property 1 and Property 2 for you entire data, your correlations are not as obvious anymore.

Also, sometimes entity's first date (the day the system was first installed) will affect how Property 1 and Property 2 relate.

The question is, how do I take all these into account to have best possible approximations for Property 2 at the unknown locations?

Answer (score 0):

I would create the column "distance" and calculate the distance between properties where both have coordinates. Then I'd look at the distribution of distances. I would try to relate the distances to all known variables, i.e. location of Property 1 and the date.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Aksakal. What do you mean by "the distance between properties where both have coordinates?"

Comment: You can calculate the distance only when Property 2 coordinates are available

Comment: Thanks Aksakal. What confuses me is that I don't understand what you mean by distance. The distance between which two points? Do you mean the distance between every pair of points? Do you want me to create a distance matrix?

Comment: Having a latitude and longitude doesn't help understanding the proximity. Minneapolis in USA and Bologna in Italy are on the same latitude. So, I'm suggesting to calculate the distance between properties in miles or kilometers instead, and use this variable for proximity

Comment: Thanks Aksakal. I don't think we're on the same page though.I know what distance means. I can calculate the distance between point 1 and point 2 but not between property 1 and property 2 (which are quantities of produced volumes). Can you maybe use an example to clarify this for me.

Comment: Maybe you should explain your data more than XXX vs. XXX